# Shift bytes of file in bash

Tags: bash, byte, shift

How can I shift some bytes of a file in bash? What I want to do is make a file corrupt to check that my program will handle corrupt files correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shift by, say, 3 bytes "left" and discard the shifted bytes:

```
$ tail -c +3 file > file.shifted
```